# Proving $3^{1/3} \notin \mathbb{Q}[13^{1/3}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

So, I need to solve a hard problem, which reduces to this:

> Prove that $3^{\frac{1}{3}} \notin \mathbb{Q}[13^{\frac{1}{3}}]$.

The only thing that comes into my mind is to suppose the opposite, *i.e.*, $3^{\frac{1}{3}} \in \mathbb{Q}[13^{\frac{1}{3}}]$, and then to see that $3^{\frac{1}{3}} = a+b\ 13^{\frac{1}{3}} + c\ 13^{\frac{2}{3}}$ leads to some contradiction while trying to manipulate this. But I am not sure if this would work.

> Is there a smarter solution, or a solution at all?

(If someone really can manipulate this, I would like to see it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $3^{\frac{1}{3}} \in \mathbb{Q}(13^{\frac{1}{3}})$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{3}})=\mathbb{Q}(13^{\frac{1}{3}})$, because both field have degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. This is a contradiction, since both fields have different [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field).

Answer (score 2):

The vector space approach is to consider $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]{13}]$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$ with the basis $1,\sqrt[3]{13},\sqrt[3]{13}^2$. Then multiplication by $a+b\sqrt[3]{13}+c\sqrt[3]{13}^2$ can be represented by the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&13c&13b\\
b&a&13c\\
c&b&a
\end{pmatrix}$$

For this to represent $\sqrt[3]{3}$, it must have minimal polynomial $x^3-3$. In particular, then, the trace must be zero, so $a=0$. And the determinant must be $3$, but the determinant when $a=0$ is obviously a multiple of $13$.